# php GD image functions. Image half way filled with specific color

Tags: php

I am testing out the php GD functions as follows:

```
$height = 200;
$width = 200;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
$blue = imagecolorallocate( $im, 0, 0, 64 );

imagefill( $im, 0, 50, $blue );

Header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng( $im );

imagedestroy( $im );
```

I was trying to have the image half way filled with blue but am not getting that result. Any pointers on where the problem is?

Comment: I think `imagefilledrectangle()` will help you do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think drawing a rectangle will help:

```
$height = 200;
$width = 200;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
$blue = imagecolorallocate( $im, 0, 0, 64 );
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill( $im, 0, 0, $white);
imagefilledrectangle( $im, 0, 0, 100, 200, $blue );

Header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng( $im );

imagedestroy( $im );
```

Should produce an image with white background and a blue rectangle from 0 to 200 along Y and 0 to 100 along X.